# CSS - full screen background image that does not crop at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Please don't flag this as being a duplicate unless you are 100% sure.

I need an image as a background image that is 100% width and height with no cropping. So it should stretch/squish however to fit the screen. However, I am unable to use an img tag for this, as that would place the image on top of other backgrounds I am using, so I have to use the background css property.

Here is the tutorial I was using for css full screen background images, that doesn't seem to be doing what I need: [CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Here is a JSfiddle of what is currently occuring: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83XLH/)

I believe this is the relevant code, which is for the `li` that contains the background image:

```
.foo {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;

    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/ZNoJHg1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Note that if you enlarge/make the render area smaller, the amount of image shown changes. This is what I am trying to avoid. I am willing to use javascript or jquery to fix this.

Comment: your jfiddle is not there

Comment: @helderdarocha Yeah, fixed that.

Comment: Doesn't `background-size: 100%;` solve your problem?

Comment: Try this tutorial, you will need to use jQuery to check for the screen size and format your background accordingly. http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: @Ljubisa That's the tutorial I posted, though I may have missed the jquery at the end... I'll look at that

Comment: @helderdarocha Just tried on the jsfiddle, nope.

Comment: @Jon Gould sorry I didn't check the link of your tutorial I just did the search my self. :)

Comment: i edit my new code.. do check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.fit {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.center {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function set_body_height() {
  var wh = $(window).height();
  $('body').height(wh); // body height = window height
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  set_body_height();
  $(window).bind('resize', function() { set_body_height(); });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="the_pic" class="center fit" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZNoJHg1.jpg" >    
</body>
</html>
```

try this one.. seem your question duplicate btw

Comment: Nope, the image still crops when resized.

Comment: can u make it bigger and resize it from right to left in that fiddle

Comment: This is now exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Add `background-size:100%;`

or change your background css like following

```
background :url("http://i.imgur.com/ZNoJHg1.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center / 100% auto rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score -2):

This solution depend on using image tag not background property and it is not covering the other image

**CSS**

```
            html,body{height: 100%;}
            body{
                margin: 0;
                position: relative;
                padding:0;


            }
            .background{
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left:0;
                z-index: 0;
            }
            .page-container
            {
                min-height: 100%;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
            }
```

**HTML**

```
<img class="background" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZNoJHg1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
<div class="page-container">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZNoJHg1.jpg" width="500" height="500" />    
</div>
```

Comment: From my post: "I am unable to use an img tag for this, as that would place the image on top of other backgrounds I am using, so I have to use the background css property."

Comment: you can use couple of backgrounds images tags with diffrent z-index values

Comment: I've tried this. Even setting img tags to z-index -999 does not put them behind background colors and other background images.